# RMAN Creating automatic instance fails

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I am trying to transport a tablespace in RMAN. The command I'm running is

```
transport tablespace usr_table auxiliary destination '/oracle/rman/auxFiles' tablespace destination '/oracle/rman';
```

The initialization parameters used for the automatic instance are

```
initialization parameters used for automatic instance:
db_name=ORCL
db_unique_name=tnpD_pitr_ORCL
compatible=12.2.0
db_block_size=8192
db_files=200
diagnostic_dest=/opt/oracle
_system_trig_enabled=FALSE
sga_target=2048M
processes=200
db_create_file_dest=/oracle/rman/auxFiles
log_archive_dest_1='location=/oracle/rman/auxFiles'
#No auxiliary parameter file used
```

The error I'm getting is

```
RMAN-03002: failure of transport tablespace command at 06/10/2020 15:32:40
RMAN-04014: startup failed: ORA-27125: unable to create shared memory segment
Linux-x86_64 Error: 28: No space left on device
Additional information: 3822
Additional information: 2130706432
```

I need to change the

```
diagnostic_dest=/opt/oracle
```

Should I make an auxiliary file and if so do I need to put all the parameters that are shown in the rman output?

Comment: 1) i recommend that you dont use an undocumented parameter (anything beginning with `_` ) unless told to do so by Oracle support. 2) your error indicates that you are out shared memory space. OS setting is in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: And likely that as @MichaelKutz said, memory issue, I ran into a similar case where the server where RMAN was creating the automatic instance was low on memory with just the existing database, so no room for the second instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that the auto_extend for one of my tablespaces had been set to off. Once I changed that I was able to run my commands